# "linkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly. Failed to resolve System.String SQLitePCL.raw::sqlite3_column_name(SQLitePCL.sqlite3_stmt,System.Int32)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am trying to debug xamarin forms project - project builds successfully, but fails with error when trying to run it.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.MobileServiceSQLiteStore::ReadRow(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.TableDefinition,SQLitePCL.sqlite3_stmt)' in assembly: 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.String SQLitePCL.raw::sqlite3_column_name(SQLitePCL.sqlite3_stmt,System.Int32)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()         0
```

Comment: Can you tell which linking behavior you have chosen? See your project settings > iOS Build or Android Build.

Comment: SDK Assemblies only

Comment: Ensure that Newtonsoft.Json is installed and has the same version in every project. Try to delete obj/bin folder and rebuild again.  Also, you can try the suggestion [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/android-linkassemblies-error);

Comment: Hi,  I tried all the suggestions - no difference. I had uninstall the current version of all SQLitePCLRaw files and re-install an earlier version. Both projects effected with this now work with the earlier version. This is hardly a fix, but will have to do in the mean time.

Comment: I find a similar [issue](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/issues/291) on Github, the author advise you to use a lower version.

Comment: @Karlitos2312 What version of SQLitePCL did you downgrade to?